# How do I make height fill between divs?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs 1 one on top, one on the bottom, and one in the middle. The top and middle div both have certain sizes. Is there any way I can get the middle div to fill the space inbetween the other two divs?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: do you mean the top and bottom have fixed heights?

Comment: This is a duplicate of _so_ many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the middle div use:

```
height: calc(100% - (XXXpx + XXXpx));
```

Here you have an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #global { height: 100vh; }
        #header { height: 100px; background-color: orange; }
        #content { height: calc(100% - (100px + 50px)); background-color: gray; }
        #footer { height: 50px; background-color: green;  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="global">
        <div id="header">
            Aenean
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            lacinia
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            quam
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Global div may have the height as you want

Answer (score 0):

I would use `calc()` which is only available with css3 browsers. The following example worked for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.fixed{height:100px; width:100%; position:absolute; left:0;}
.top{background:#f00; top:0;}
.mid{background:#0f0; height:calc(100% - 200px); padding-top:100px;}
.bot{background:#00f; bottom:0;}    
</style>

<div class="fixed top"></div>
<div class="mid"></div>
<div class="fixed bot"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div
{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#top
{
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
}

#middle
{
    background: green;
    bottom: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}

#bottom
{
    background: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="middle">middle</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/xwatfwcL/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using flexbox.

[JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jaa8qfbL/)

Solution:

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    height: 100%;
}

#row1 {
    background-color: #678678;
    height: 50px
}

#row2 {
    background-color: #e34e34;
    flex:2;
    display: flex;
}

#row3 {
    background-color: #987987;
    height: 66px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="row1">top</div>
    <div id="row2">middle</div>
    <div id="row3">bottom</div>
</div>
```